# Puzzle: numerical pattern recognition

Tags: puzzle

IF

```
7 - 3 = 10124
6 + 3 = 3279
5 – 2 = 763
11 + 2 = 92613
```

Then,

```
15 - 3 =?
```

Any ideas ? I dont know how I am supposed to go about solving puzzles like this one ? is there any strategy ? any algorithm ?

Comment: That is one weird way to use `+`, `-`, or `=`...

Comment: @J.M. is it a symbolic question ? or is based on number representation ? any ideas ?

Comment: I'm just noting that those symbols you're using do not seem to be playing their conventional uses in your question.

Comment: All of the "answers" end in what the actual answer should be (4,9,3,13), and start with the reverse operation (7-3 => 7+3 => 10 -- and similarly 6-3 = 3, 5+2 = 7, 11-2=9).

Comment: 12 =D lol... kidding. The problem with this puzzle is that whatever answer we get we won't be satisfied with it.

Comment: It reminds me of a puzzle where you had to count the number of edges. So $a = b \not \Leftrightarrow b = a$ as you apply a function `getNumberOfEdges` to the left. So (if this was handwriting) 1 = 1, 2 = 1, 3 = 0, 4 =1, 5 = 2, 13 = 1, ...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is all I can come up with:

1:  Do the operation, the answer to that will be placed on the far right:

$
\begin{align}
7-3 &= 4 \\
6 + 3 &=9 \\
5-2 &= 3 \\
11 + 2 &= 13
\end{align}$

2:  Take the solution from above, multiply by the second digit in the original expression.  Place it to the left of the answer we got in 1.:

$
\begin{align}
4\cdot 3 &= 12 \\
9\cdot 3&=27 \\
3\cdot 2&= 6 \\ 
13 \cdot 2 &= 26
\end{align}$

So, we have

$
\begin{align}
124 \\
279 \\
63 \\ 
2613
\end{align}$

3:  If the original operation was addition, subtract, and vice versa.  Stick this number to the left of the concatenated solutions to 1 and 2:

$
\begin{align}
7+3 &= 10 \\
6 - 3 &=3 \\
5+2 &= 7 \\
11 - 2 &= 9
\end{align}$

Thus, we have

$
\begin{align}
10124 \\
3279 \\
763 \\ 
92613
\end{align}$

Comment: You were 3 mins behind Thomas's answer, but i guess it took you more than 3 mins to format this answer. Hence selected your answer cos it was the fastest.

Answer (score 8):

It would be $15-3 = 183612$. Answers are $(\text{opposite operation})(\text{answer} \times\text{second operand})(\text{actual computation})$

Answer (score 6):

**WARNING: full answer**

Note that 7 + 3 = 10, (7-3)*3 = 12, 7 - 3 = 4
Concatenate to get 10124

For the next one, 6 - 3 = 3, (6+3)*3 = 27, and 6+3 = 9
Concatenate to get 3279

Do a similar process for the other two.  Its a weird pattern, but its there.  And there isn't a general way to solve stuff like that, its just pattern recognition.

Comment: ya, its pattern recognition; and you sir, rock at it !

Answer (score 1):

15-3 =?

(15+3)((15-3)*3)(15-3)

183612

Comment: Yes, that is what all the other answers have said.